# Error messages flash up briefly during boot and shutdown - are these logged anywhere?

Tags: error-handling, logs

I get errors at the beginning of Ubuntu startup. But it disappear fast, because of this I am not able to see the errors.  Also while shutting down i see some of the errors. Want to know what it is. 
Is there any logs to track these errors? that will be helpful to check what it is.

Comment: Check out the `/var/log/syslog` log file and the `dmesg` command.

Comment: @muru thanks for the path..I will look into it and will investigate the error further

Comment: @muru your comment could probably be an answer.  I don't wanna steal your rep by basically just reposting exactly what's in your comment.

Comment: @neon_overload sure, go ahead. :) I figured OP will come back and edit the question to show us the errors, making my answer obsolete quickly. That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the messages from boot go into dmesg, which can be read using the `dmesg` command or at `/var/log/dmesg` - particularly if they are kernel messages.

Some messages will go into `/var/log/syslog`, particularly if they are from services or startup scripts.