# How to see errors that appears before shutdown of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Every time when I shutdown my Ubuntu 14.04 PC, I got a black screen showing some warnings just for 1 second. It was very fast to read it. It's not about OS or hardware, maybe it is server related that I've installed recently. So how to see it? Please advise, thanks.

I got this after running this command:

```
grep -iE 'mysql|server' /var/log/syslog /var/log/kern.log

Dec 27 00:01:02  dnsmasq[1363]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:01:20  dnsmasq[1677]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:01:22 NetworkManager[911]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:01:23  dnsmasq[1363]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:01:23 dnsmasq[1363]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:01:32  ntpdate[8178]: no server suitable for synchronization found
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:02:51dnsmasq[1677]: using nameserver 127.0.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 00:02:51  dnsmasq[1363]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:08:02 5 ntpdate[825]: no servers can be used, exiting
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:08:02  bluetoothd[830]: Starting SDP server
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:08:02  avahi-daemon[827]: Server startup complete. Host name is .local. Local service cookie is 2471667593.
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:08:12 dnsmasq[1671]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:30 NetworkManager[905]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:31 NetworkManager[905]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:31  dnsmasq[2068]: warning: no upstream servers configured
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:32 5 dnsmasq[2068]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:32 dnsmasq[2068]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:09:39  ntpdate[2186]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.337961 sec
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:11:26 -1545 dnsmasq[1671]: using nameserver 127.0.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:29 ntpdate[826]: no servers can be used, exiting
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:29  bluetoothd[809]: Starting SDP server
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:29 avahi-daemon[843]: Server startup complete. Host name is .local. Local service cookie is 3166850630.
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:34 NetworkManager[907]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:35 NetworkManager[907]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:36  dnsmasq[1348]: warning: no upstream servers configured
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:38 dnsmasq[1348]: setting upstream servers from DBus
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:38  dnsmasq[1348]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:41  dnsmasq[1970]: using nameserver 127.0.1.1#53
/var/log/syslog:Dec 27 07:36:46  ntpdate[1648]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.336311 sec
```

By the way, the actual warning/error was not very large like the above. It was may be 2/3 lines.

Comment: Check in `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @heemayl the error/warning that appears , was not in  these log files.i just checked them.thanks

Comment: can you tell any keyword or hint?

Comment: @heemayl  some kewords were:  mysql, server, etc.

Comment: Try `grep -iE 'mysql|server' /var/log/syslog /var/log/kern.log` ..there might be a bunch of entries as there are somewhat common terms..

Comment: @heemayl  i just  edited the output that suggest me in the post please check.thanks

Comment: Check if its related to `ntp`

Comment: @heemay No it was not ntp related.

Comment: It's very hard to track it given the very little info we have..heres an upvote, hope someone can get it sorted out..

Comment: If the relevant error/messages are not in `*.log`, check older, rotated logs `*.log.0`,  `*.log.1`, etc.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/103015/how-do-i-check-if-last-shutdown-was-clean

Comment: And this (all similar questions with incomplete answers that could be merged) : http://askubuntu.com/questions/528159/error-messages-flash-up-briefly-during-boot-and-shutdown-are-these-logged-anyw